# my battery capacity shows 58.7%. I use Ubuntu 19.10. how to get 100% capacity? please help me

Tags: 19.10, battery

[image: please help me.]

it shows my battery capacity is 58.7%.

Comment: Replace the battery.

Comment: Usually, that means the battery is damaged or defective. There is no way to repair.